# projecting a 3D helix on to XY plane

Tags: python, math, geometry, helix

How can I project a 3D helix (XYZ cartesian coordinates) onto the XY plane. Basically I want to project different 3D helices from XYZ to XY plane.

Comment: There are a million ways to do [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection). Which one are you looking for and what exactly is your problem? The formulas are not really hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

for each `point=(x, y, z)` Set `z = 0`, and use the 2D `(x, y)` coordinates to obtain an orthographic projection on the x, y plane.

Comment: what would be the equations? I can calculate the azimuthal and dip angle at each point and I want to use them for accurcay.

Comment: for an orthographic projection, you only have to set z to zero.